# Why isn't the GPU incrementing the atomic counter every pixel?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

According to [this](https://www.ozone3d.net/public/jegx/201112/geexlab-opengl-atomic-counter-demo-gtx460.jpg) blog page, the following shader writes the framebuffer pixel with the value of the atomic counter:

```
#version 420 compatibility
layout(binding = 0, offset = 0) uniform atomic_uint ac;
void main(void)
{
  uint counter = atomicCounterIncrement(ac);
  float r = (counter/255) / 255.f;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(r, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

They are doing / 255 / 255 because the image is 256 x 256 pixels. While on some GPUs this is the result:

[image]

On other GPUs this is the result:

[image]

The darker pixels are lower values of the counter obviously. Why isn't it that the atomic counter isn't being incremented for every pixel shader invocation?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but I think it is? It looks like the difference is just the "order of execution" (I mean, in which order the pixels are processed). But it's early in the morning in my timezone. I may need more coffee.

Comment: Atomic counters are not a feature of Vulkan. The blog post is about OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

`counter/255` divides one integer by another. Just like in C or C++, this results in an *integer*, not a floating point value. As such, 255 fragment shader invocations will get the same result.

That's probably the intent of the code.

As to the more orderly arrangement in one picture vs. the other, that's all implementation-dependent.